# Error: Unknown type "Query". at assertValidSDL (GRAPHQL)

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

```
throw new Error(errors.map(function (error) {
    ^
Error: Unknown type "Query".
    at assertValidSDL (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\graphql\validation\validate.js:107:11)
    at Object.buildASTSchema (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\graphql\utilities\buildASTSchema.js:45:34)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\generate\buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:25:28)
    at Object.makeExecutableSchema (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29)
    at ApolloServer.initSchema (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:273:49)
    at new ApolloServerBase (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\apollo-server-core\dist\ApolloServer.js:196:30)
    at new ApolloServer (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\node_modules\apollo-server-express\dist\ApolloServer.js:59:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sowmica\Desktop\graphql\udemy\gql\server\server.js:23:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**
```

Please help me to solve this error I can't understand from the error message. I also referred to similar issues in git but none helped. Please give me a possible solution!
This is my github repository link

https://github.com/SowmicaML/graphql

Thank You in advance.

Comment: The error is produced because there is no definition for the Query type. The `typeDefs` folder is not in the same as your `server.js` so this `path.join(__dirname, "./typeDefs")` is not looking correctly. Also, in both your `/typeDefs` files: `auth.js` and `post.js` you are missing the closing `}`. So, move your `typeDefs` folder into "/server" and add the `}`

Comment: Thank you so much.I had solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You should post the relevant code samples directly into your question, because links can be dead in the future. One thing i have noticed is that you are missing closing `}` in your typeDefs.
Example from `auth.js`

```
const { gql } = require("apollo-server-express");

module.exports = gql`
type Query {
    me: String!
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import correct typeDef and revolvers in types/index.ts and resolvers/index.ts
Sometimes it import model in types/revolvers, That cause the issue for me